# emacs-show-diff-output produces empty buffer

Tags: ediff, diff

**EDIT**: I figured it out. It seems to be an emacs bug. My walk-through of the bug is below.

I just now found out about `emacs-show-diff-output`, which is bound to <kbd>D</kbd> by default in an ediff session.

When I make changes to a buffer without saving the file and then run `M-x ediff-current-file` to start an ediff session for the changes that haven't been saved, if I then press <kbd>D</kbd>, a new frame pops up with a buffer named `*ediff-custom-diff*`, but it's empty.

The `*Messages*` buffer shows:

```
Computing differences between ediff100678ZHa and built-in.el ...
Buffer A: Processing difference region 0 of 1
Buffer B: Processing difference region 0 of 1
Processing difference regions ... done
```

I tried searching around but couldn't find anything related to `ediff-show-diff-output`. Anyone have any idea as to what may be happening?

**EDIT**: I've noticed that if I do it from an ediff session initiated from magit with `E w` (ediff of the working tree changes), then <kbd>D</kbd> works fine. It seems to be when I do it via `M-x ediff-current-file` that it results in an empty diff. My guess would be that perhaps the file isn't found or something but the `*Messages*` output seems to show that it *is* working? It's just not ending up in the buffer.

**EDIT**: I've been stepping through the function `ediff-compute-custom-diffs-maybe`:

```
;; This function operates only from an ediff control buffer
(defun ediff-compute-custom-diffs-maybe ()
  (let ((buf-A-file-name (buffer-file-name ediff-buffer-A))
    (buf-B-file-name (buffer-file-name ediff-buffer-B))
    file-A file-B)
    (unless (and buf-A-file-name
         (file-exists-p buf-A-file-name)
         (not (ediff-file-remote-p buf-A-file-name)))
      (setq file-A (ediff-make-temp-file ediff-buffer-A)))
    (unless (and buf-B-file-name
         (file-exists-p buf-B-file-name)
         (not (ediff-file-remote-p buf-B-file-name)))
      (setq file-B (ediff-make-temp-file ediff-buffer-B)))
    (or (ediff-buffer-live-p ediff-custom-diff-buffer)
    (setq ediff-custom-diff-buffer
          (get-buffer-create
           (ediff-unique-buffer-name "*ediff-custom-diff" "*"))))
    (ediff-with-current-buffer ediff-custom-diff-buffer
                   (setq buffer-read-only nil)
                   (erase-buffer))
    (ediff-exec-process
     ediff-custom-diff-program ediff-custom-diff-buffer 'synchronize
     ediff-custom-diff-options
     (or file-A buf-A-file-name)
     (or file-B buf-B-file-name))
    ;; put the diff file in diff-mode, if it is available
    (if (fboundp 'diff-mode)
    (with-current-buffer ediff-custom-diff-buffer
      (diff-mode)))
    (and file-A (file-exists-p file-A) (delete-file file-A))
    (and file-B (file-exists-p file-B) (delete-file file-B))
    ))
```

Let's go through it a bit at a time. First here's an outline of what I believe is occurring in the first few lines:

1. get the file paths backing the buffers being compared
2. the one for which there is no file path is the one for which ediff needs to create a temporary file for with the contents of the buffer, the unchanged file can simply be read from disk

So first it tries to get the file name of each buffer:

```
  (let ((buf-A-file-name (buffer-file-name ediff-buffer-A))
    (buf-B-file-name (buffer-file-name ediff-buffer-B))
```

When you run `M-x ediff-current-file`, the left buffer (A) represents the unmodified file on disk and it's called `FILE=/path/to/file`. The buffer representing the unsaved changes is on the right (B) and it's named after the file on disk.

So what ends up happening here is that, perhaps because buffer A has a `FILE=` prefix, `buffer-file-name` fails so that `buf-A-file-name` is `nil`. Meanwhile, buffer B which again represents the dirty unsaved buffer *does* succeed on `buffer-file-name` and sets `buf-B-file-name` to the file path to the underlying file.

```
    (unless (and buf-A-file-name
         (file-exists-p buf-A-file-name)
         (not (ediff-file-remote-p buf-A-file-name)))
      (setq file-A (ediff-make-temp-file ediff-buffer-A)))
```

This part then executes if `buf-A-file-name` is `nil`, which it is, so it proceeds to set `file-A` to a temporary file that it creates from the contents of buffer A. **In effect** this creates a temporary file with the same contents as the *unchanged file* on disk.

Now it's B's turn:

```
    (unless (and buf-B-file-name
         (file-exists-p buf-B-file-name)
         (not (ediff-file-remote-p buf-B-file-name)))
      (setq file-B (ediff-make-temp-file ediff-buffer-B)))
```

In this case `buf-B-file-name` is not `nil`, the file does exist, and it's not a remote file, so it *doesn't* create a temporary file for buffer B, instead it'll simply read the *unchanged file* on disk.

So at this point we now have:

1. a temporary file with the contents of the unchanged file
2. the unchanged file on the disk

These are clearly equivalent, so running `diff` on them produces no output, hence the empty buffer.

I've **confirmed** that this is the problem by "fixing" the visited files of the ediff buffers. So I focus buffer A and run:

```
(set-visited-file-name "/path/to/file")
```

I focus buffer B and run:

```
(set-visited-file-name "DIRTY=/path/to/file")
```

Then I press <kbd>D</kbd> again (`M-x ediff-show-diff-output`) and [**IT WORKS!!**](https://i.imgur.com/S4KbHcz.png).

So to recap, I believe the problem is that the `FILE=` prefix added to buffer A which represents the file on disk makes ediff think that it's actually the dirty buffer for which it needs to create a temporary file, albeit with the contents of buffer A which is the contents of the file. *Then* it goes on to buffer B and it determines that the file backing that buffer is the unchanged file on disk, when really it should actually determine that it's the dirty buffer and create a temporary file with the contents of the dirty buffer. In the end we end up with a temporary file and the unchanged file both with the same contents, so diff produces no output and thus an empty buffer.

I'm not sure how to go about solving this. Perhaps I can change the names with a setup-hook but that may be fragile.

Comment: Please `M-x report-emacs-bug`